# QnA Maker gives different scores on each Training

Tags: azure, azure-qna-maker

I am using QnA Maker with nodejs.

Steps to reproduce, In the created KB

`Add a file -> Save and Train`

Test with random text

```
remove file -> Save and Train

Again add the same file -> Save and Train
```

Test same chars _

Is there anything I can do to get same score, or is this expected one ?

Answer (score 1):

QnA results are non-deterministic. What this means is the returned result can and will vary by small degrees following every API call with the same query. If you need to improve confidence scores, look over [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/concepts/confidence-score) document for suggestions.